# MySQL trigger somehow causes commit

Tags: mysql, hibernate, triggers

We have a simple auditing system on several tables. This all works fine, but every once in a while, we get an error like this on an operation that causes the trigger to fire:

`java.sql.SQLException: Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger.`

Unfortunately, we cannot figure out how our triggers could cause a commit.

These are the triggers that (sometimes) cause the error:

```
CREATE
TRIGGER `my_schema`.`fileDescriptorInsertTrigger`
AFTER INSERT ON `my_schema`.`FILE_DESCRIPTOR`
FOR EACH ROW
    insert into `AUDIT_EVENT`
            (`applicationId`,`classifier`,`lastModified`)
        values
            (NEW.application,'FILE_AND_DIR',NOW())
    on duplicate key
        update lastModified=NOW();

CREATE
TRIGGER `my_schema`.`fileDescriptorUpdateTrigger`
AFTER UPDATE ON `my_schema`.`FILE_DESCRIPTOR`
FOR EACH ROW
    update `AUDIT_EVENT`
      set lastModified=NOW()
      where classifier='FILE_AND_DIR'
        and applicationId=NEW.application;

CREATE
TRIGGER `my_schema`.`fileDescriptorDeleteTrigger`
AFTER DELETE ON `my_schema`.`FILE_DESCRIPTOR`
FOR EACH ROW
    update `AUDIT_EVENT`
      set lastModified=NOW()
      where classifier='FILE_AND_DIR'
        and applicationId=OLD.application;
```

**Edit: upon request, output of `show variables like '%commit%'`**

```
Variable_name   Value
innodb_commit_concurrency   0
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  1
```

**Edit 2**

The error only tends to happen after an `INSERT` on `my_schema.FILE_DESCRIPTOR`, so that would narrow it down to the `INSERT TRIGGER` but even then I have no clue how it could cause a commit.

We do have Hibernate on top of this, so it's actually Hibernate that's doing the inserts, and we also have an entity mapped on the `AUDIT_EVENT` table, but Hibernate (should) never write to the `AUDIT_EVENT` table.

I uploaded a [full stacktrace](http://pastebin.com/fmTNNd2k) if that helps.

Comment: Post results of `show variables like '%commit%'` pls. I suppose you turn off auto_commit

Comment: I edited my original post with the output you requested.

Comment: Are absolutely all of the tables involved `InnoDB` tables? If you're mixing storage engines you could get yourself into trouble.

Comment: @jeremycole I checked using `select * from information_schema.TABLES where ENGINE not like 'InnoDB';` and all the tables in that resultset are tables in the `information_schema` schema.

Comment: So a trigger on FILE_DESCRIPTOR does DML on table AUDIT_EVENT. Now, do you have triggers on AUDIT_EVENT by any chance ?

Comment: 1) Can you turn on Hibernats logging of what SQL it's doing - log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG I think.

2) The things that cause an implicit commit are listed at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/implicit-commit.html - I can't see you doing any of them.

Comment: 3) Do you have any of those things that do an implicit commit anywhere in your SQL, and could they be being triggered?

And yeah - what triggers do you have on AUDIT_EVENT.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I already found that list of things that cause implicit commits, and I can't find any of those in my triggers.
To make sure, I selected all triggers in my DB using `select * from information_schema.TRIGGERS;`, and all of them cause either an `insert` or `update` on `AUDIT_EVENT`. `AUDIT_EVENT` itself does not have any triggers on it.

Comment: About hibernate logging - I'll see what I can do. We haven't been able to reproduce this issue in a test environment, so I'd have to enable sql logging on our production servers. That's a lot of logging :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because of **DEADLOCK** that's why explicit Commit/Rollback happens.
Please try to handle this activity.
Here is some links that may help you.

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=24989

http://lists.mysql.com/commits/27471

**Try to use read-committed isolation level.**

```
transaction-isolation = READ-COMMITTED
```

**This may resolve your problem. Here is Links for reference**

http://www.toofishes.net/blog/mysql-deadlocking-simple-inserts/

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-deadlocks.html

Hope this will help.